# BPSK angle deviation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, complex-numbers

I have a problem with BPSK signal processing. I want to determine angle deviation of the signal constellation.

I have an idea to make it based on quadrature, as in example below. But it is not suitable for cases when noisy constellations intersect the 1 and 4 quarter axes. In this case, the result is unsatisfactory - the script considers the mean angle only for a part of the constellation.

```
th = angle(x);
if nnz(th < pi/2 & th > 0) > nnz(th > pi/2 & th>0) 
    mth = rad2deg(mean(th(th < pi/2 & th > 0)));
else
    mth = rad2deg(-pi + mean(th(th >= pi/2 & th > 0)));
end
```

Results:

Real signal (unsatisfactory)
[image: Real signal (unsatisfactory)]

Test signal (ok)
[image: Test signal (ok)]

Test signal (not ok)
[image: Test signal (not ok)]

Noise in real signal it is sinuslikehood pilot signal.

Second script:

```
ma = rad2deg(angle(mean(x(x >= 0)))); 
mb = rad2deg(angle(mean(x(x<0)))); 
mth = (ma + (rad2deg(pi) + mb))/2;
```

Here I'm checking mean angle in 2 areas. But it is too incorrect, since when signal intersect the 1 and 2 quarter axes, script doesn't work.

Results:

Real signal (not ok)
[image: Real signal (not ok)]

Test signal (ok)
[image: Test signal (ok)]

Test signal (not ok)
[image: Test signal (not ok)]

Given all those previous results, I think that I should get away from quadrature. So, I have following questions:
How can I find the average angle of the constellation without reference to the quadratures?

Maybe there exists some standard method for finding mean constellation angle?

Answer (score 0):

Use [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)  function to determine which quadrant received symbol is in.  And then subtract angle of received symbol from ideal symbol to get phase error.